# How do i check in java, if a file is locked/used by some other process.? something like openfiles command in powershell?

Tags: java, spring

i am trying to overwrite a file on FTP, but i am getting the error that file is being used by other process while posting.because on FTP, customer's API is reading the file which i am trying to overwrite.Is there any way i can check in my JAVA code that if a file is busy/locked by other processes ? so that i can retry posting once the file is not busy or locked ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow

You can use `java.nio.channels.FileChannel` to check if file is lock or not. [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html)

You can use tryLock method.

Hope this helps